# Compare/filter two arrays where array B contains any substring of A

Tags: javascript, typescript

Okay, so this is something i partially have working (ignoring case sensitivity) comparing the following:

```
arrayA = ["apples", "Oranges", "salt", "Cracked Black Pepper"];
arrayB = ["salt", "pepper", "orange"]
```

which works 'partially' with the following:

```
findAnyMatch(arrayA, arrayB): string[] {
    let returnArray = [];
    let conditionedArrayA = arrayA.map(i => i.toLowerCase().trim())
    for (let i = 0; i < arrayB.length; i++) {
      if (conditionedArrayA .includes(arrayB[i].toLowerCase().trim())) {
        ret.push(arrayB[i].toLowerCase().trim());
      }
    }
    return returnArray;
  }
```

Which returns: `"salt", "orange"` quite happily; the problem being that it can't see "pepper" in arrayA because it has "cracked black" in front of it.

How do i get it to search anywhere inside each string of the conditioned arrayA?

Thanks

Comment: The title of your question and the problem description in your body are at odds. "Cracked Black Pepper" is not a substring of "pepper", but ignoring case sensitivity, "pepper" is a substring of "Cracked Black Pepper". Was your question intended to be "filter two arrays where array B contains any substring of A"?

Comment: Good point, changed it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use filter and some. with regex

- Filter is used to get desired values only.
- Some is used to check if any of values in `arrayA` matches with current element.
- Regex is used to match the string. `i` flag is used for case insensitivity.

```js
let arrayA = ["apples", "Oranges", "salt", "Cracked Black Pepper"];
let arrayB = ["salt", "pepper", "orange"]

let find = (A,B) => {
  return B.filter(b=> A.some(a=> new RegExp(b,'i').test(a)))
}

console.log(find(arrayA,arrayB))
```

Comment: Just a side note, make sure that your arrays aren't strings that come from user input in any way. If they are, use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3561711/1541563) for escaping the strings before passing them to the [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) constructor or you'll end up with a vulnerability.

Answer (score 1):

Since `arrayB` contains the "needles", and `arrayA` contains the "haystacks", so to speak, you can use [`String.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes). Note you are actually using [`Array.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) in your attempt, which is why it only matches `"salt"` (based on your example code, I am highly doubtful that even `"orange"` was a successful match).

Below is a solution that uses `String.prototype.includes()` instead:

```js
function matchedSubstrings (haystacks, needles) {
  return needles.filter(function (needle) {
    const lowerCaseNeedle = needle.toLowerCase()
    return this.some(haystack => haystack.includes(lowerCaseNeedle))
  }, haystacks.map(haystack => haystack.toLowerCase()))
}

const arrayA = ["apples", "Oranges", "salt", "Cracked Black Pepper"]
const arrayB = ["Salt", "pepper", "orange"]

console.log(matchedSubstrings(arrayA, arrayB))
```

The `this` of the [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) callback function is the transformed `haystacks` array passed as the second argument.

The equivalent TypeScript is as follows:

```
function matchedSubstrings (haystacks: string[], needles: string[]): string[] {
  return needles.filter(function (this: string[], needle) {
    const lowerCaseNeedle = needle.toLowerCase()
    return this.some(haystack => haystack.includes(lowerCaseNeedle))
  }, haystacks.map(haystack => haystack.toLowerCase()))
}

const arrayA = ["apples", "Oranges", "salt", "Cracked Black Pepper"]
const arrayB = ["Salt", "pepper", "orange"]

console.log(matchedSubstrings(arrayA, arrayB))
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let arrayA = ["apples", "Oranges", "salt", "Cracked Black Pepper"];
let arrayB = ["salt", "pepper", "orange"]

let find = (A,B) => {
  return B.filter(b=> A.some(a=> new RegExp(b,'i').test(a)))
}

console.log(find(arrayA,arrayB))
```